# Rails/Capistrano: check if sidekiq is running on an EC2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, sidekiq

I'm using an EC2 instance for hosting a rails application. I'm deploying with capistrano and I had already included sidekiq and it's working fine. However, sometimes on deploy, and sometimes sporadically, sidekiq stops running and I don't notice until some tasks that use sidekiq doesn't run.

I could do something on deploy to check that, but if it stops to work eventually after deploy, that would still be a problem.

I would like to know what is the best way, in that scenario, to check periodically if sidekiq is running, and if not to, run it.

I thought of doing a bash script for that, but apparently, when I run sidekiq from command line, it creates another process with a different pid of the one launched by sidekiq... so I think it could get messy. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Would using `ps aux | grep sidekiq` help?

Comment: @Ruslan I can do that to check manually... but think the best way is to have some routine that checks it automatically every day, for example.

Comment: What i meant is in your deploy script, you could run that command and start up sidekiq if it is not running

Comment: @Ruslan yeah, but the problem is that sometimes it happens of it get stuck eventually some time after the deploy... so if I keep a long time without deploying and it stops in that meanwhile, I wouldn't notice

Comment: This will require more of a `cron` scrip solution then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn and use systemd to manage the service.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#running-your-own-process

Comment: I'll take a look at that. Thank you!